# Функция =IMPORTRANGE [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть два значения, которые нужно вытянуть из таблицы `<<A>>` в `<<B>>`. В таблице `<<B>>` мне нужно, чтобы цифра 1, берущаяся из таблицы `<<A>>` делилась на цифру из той же таблицы `<<A>>` в рамках одной ячейки. Через `=IMPORTRANGE` получается вытянуть 1 значение, оно отображается корректно, но когда пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы оно второе число тянуло через `=IMPORTRANGE` и они между собой делились в рамках одной ячейки - ничего не получается. Совсем новичок в таблицах, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у вас в таблице `<<A>>` данные, которые вы хотите тянуть и делить находятся на листе `Лист1` в ячейках `A1` и `B1` и вам нужно поделить значения из `A1` на `B1`, тогда формула будет выглядеть так:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID таблицы из которой тяните данные"; "Лист1!A1") / IMPORTRANGE("ID таблицы из которой тяните данные"; "Лист1!B1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Такое ощущение, что Вам нужна связка с QUERY

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("id";"source!A1:B1");"SELECT Col1/Col2")
```